# Migrate JSON to HSTORE

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.4, hstore

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.

Initially I had on my **USERS** table a **DETAILS** field that was an **HSTORE** field type.

I updated that column type from **HSTORE** to **JSONB** very easily using:

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN details TYPE jsonb USING CAST(details AS jsonb)
```

The issue I'm facing now is that I have to write a rollback but I was not able to find a way to cast from **JSONB** to **HSTORE**.

I've tried using:

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN details TYPE hstore USING CAST(details AS hstore)
```

And got:

```
ERROR: cannot cast type jsonb to hstore
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the jsonb values are in the simple form of pairs `{"key":"value",...}`, you can use this function:

```
create or replace function simple_jsonb_to_hstore(jdata jsonb)
returns hstore language sql immutable
as $$
    select hstore(array_agg(key), array_agg(value))
    from jsonb_each_text(jdata)
$$;

ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN details TYPE hstore USING simple_jsonb_to_hstore(details);
```